# I have some problems with reloading page in AJAX success function

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

Please help me i need to reload page after successful member login.
This is my code but nothing changes (page doesn't reload). 
Note: I am using Laravel 5.4

```
    $.ajax({
                url: 'json/login',
                type: "POST",
                data : {
                        'email' : $("#connection :input[name='email']").val(),
                        'pwd' : $("#connection :input[name='pwd']").val(),
                        '_token' : $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
                },
                dataType : "json",
                success: function(data,statusText,xhr){
                    if(data.success == 'ok'){
                         $(document).ajaxStop(function() { location.reload(true); });
                    }else{
                        $("#alert_danger").html(data.message);
                        $("#alert_danger").slideDown(100).delay(2000).slideUp(100);
                        $("#alert_success").slideUp(100);

                    }

                }
        });
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should just do this :-

```
if(data.success == 'ok'){
     location.reload(true);
}
```

Using $(document).ajaxStop does not make sense since you are already in the success function.

Comment: yes Ankit Guar  i already use location.reload(true); but d'ont work

Answer (score 0):

try window.location.reload();
This might work

Comment: Thanks I I found the solution

Comment: Cheers..@C.Azzeddine let me know what did you do.